# Multiple figures with subplots from a dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy, subplot

I have a dataframe for which I am plotting the sorted values from the columns as a line and then plotting and labeling various percentiles along that line.

I would like to have 12 subplots per figure and as many figures as I need depending on the number of columns (which will vary on my real datasets).

Here is a version of my script with a simple dataframe. This example produces 2 figures, each with 12 subplots. There are only 17 entries in the dataframe, so one figure has 7 emply subplots. This is the result that I need, however, the script is not elegant and not effiecient.

I am learning python and tend to revert back to old scripting habits when I can't figure out the efficient python way. Could someone show me how to produce the same figures with more elegant python? If I don't have 7 empty subplots, that fine too. I've tried various combinations.  I think I'm getting tripped up on not understanding the inner workings of `pandas` versus `numpy`.  I have a pandas Dataframe, but am manipulating the columns with numpy functions.  In my trials I had many errors when attempting to apply the `np.sort` to the dataframe columns, which is why I reverted back to taking a single column at a time out of the dataframe to manipulate and then plot.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 17)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ'))
p = np.array([0.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0, 90.0, 95.0, 99.0, 100.0])
j=2
i=1
fig, axs = plt.subplots(4,3, figsize=(8.5, 11), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
for f in df.columns:
    d=df[f]
    d=np.sort(d)
    perc = np.nanpercentile(d, p)
    if i >12:
       fig, axs = plt.subplots(4,3, figsize=(8.5, 11), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
       i=1
       j=j+1
    plt.subplot(4, 3, i)
    plt.plot(d)
    plt.plot((len(df[f])-1) * p/100., perc, 'ro')
    plt.xticks((len(df[f])-1)* p/100., map(str, p))
    plt.show()
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach

- create all figures and axes upfront and flatten the array of axes
- then use more unto date Matplotlib API to **plot** against axis
- have used **pandas** instead of **numpy** as I found it simpler to define x-co-ordinates from index of series rather than an array
- the x-axis is still somewhat ugly even after rotation as you want ticks that are close together for 90+ percentiles

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(15, 17)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQ'))
p = np.array([0.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0, 90.0, 95.0, 99.0, 100.0])

# create all the figures and axis that are going to be used...
axs = np.array([])
for _ in range(math.ceil(len(df.columns)/12)):
    fig, ax_t = plt.subplots(4,3, figsize=(8.5, 11), facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=0.4)
    axs = np.concatenate((axs, np.array(ax_t).flatten()))

for i, ax in enumerate(np.array(axs)):
    # NB will have created empty axis where there is no column
    if i==len(df.columns): break
    d = df.loc[:,df.columns[i]].sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)
    ax.plot(d.index/(len(df)-1), d)
    q = d.quantile(p/100)
    ax.plot(q, "ro")
    ax.set_xticks(p/100)
    ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation = 90)
    # annotate 0th, 50th and 100th percentiles
    for a in q.loc[[0,.5,1]].index:
        ax.annotate(round(q[a],1), xy=(a, q[a]),  xycoords='data', xytext=(3, 3), textcoords='offset points',)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to use `d.quantile()` in `ax.annotate()` so that I can label the scatter points?  In my previous script I had seperate variables that I used for the `(x,y)` in both `ax.plot` and `ax.annotate()`. But in the above example, `d.quantile()` is used for `ax.plot`.  How do I pull out the info to use in `ax.annotate`?

Comment: I've updated - straight forward... I've never used annotations before in matplotlib